# How to prove this series to be convergent?

Tags: calculus, analysis

For$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-na}$$ I have no idea about it.Is there any way to deal with it?thx~

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry,I forgot it ,$a>0$

Comment: When is the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n$ convergent?

Comment: @dgrasines517 For $|x|<1$?

Comment: therefore, $e^{-a}$ must be in the interval $(-1,1)$, which means $a>0$

Comment: @dgrasines517 Thanks!

Comment: @user152441, it is **important** you edit your question and add that all-important condition $\;a>0\;$ !

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^ke^{-n}\approx k!~$ See [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for $\;a>0\;$ we have straightforward from the $\;n$-th root test:

$$\sqrt[n]{ne^{-an}}=\sqrt[n]n\,e^{-a}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^{-a}<1$$

and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) since the function $f(x) = xe^{-ax}$ is strictly decreasing beyond a certain point:

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = e^{-ax} -axe^{-ax} = e^{-ax}(1 - ax)$$

Comment: I don't follow: what does the integral test have to do with the derivative of $\;f(x)\;$ ...?

Comment: Well, if I'm not mistaken, you can only apply the integral test if $f$ is monotone decreasing on an unbounded interval $[N, \infty)$ for some $N \in \mathbb{R}$.  By taking the derivative, we can see that this is true in this case.

Comment: Now I see your point, @Kaj. Thanks.